# Why does the paper award jury have access to the author names in some blinded publication venues, prior to deciding to whom the award should go to?

Tags: publications, anonymity, awards

Quite often, in publication venues where the author names are not visible to the reviewers and where some paper award is given, the authors are not blinded to the individuals who decide to whom the paper award should go to. Why?

Assume that the award decision is made prior to publications or conference presentations, which is quite common, so no event such as presentations breaks the authors' anonymity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only know of one conference where this is done, the [Gordon Bell Prize](http://awards.acm.org/bell/), and the Best Paper and Best Student Paper prizes. The are all judged, unblinded, after all the candidate talks have been presented at the [Supercomputing conference](http://sc16.supercomputing.org/) because the quality of each talk plays into the jurors' opinions about the work. The papers themselves are examined first, double-blind by completely different review panels earlier in the year in order to decide whether to accept them to the confernce or not.

For conference papers, this makes a lot of sense because the talk is a part of the criteria for the award. I ignored your suggestion about the timing of the award, because this is the only case I know of that both reviews the paper and gives a prize. If you're interested in a case where the talk is irrelevant, please update your question with specifics.

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed interested in a case where the talk is not taken into account to give the award.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, your original post makes it sound like you know of a case. Can you list it? The only case I know of includes the talk in the criteria.